# See recently used commands in imenu style

Tags: emacs, menubar

In emacs, I like to see recently used commands always visible, for buffer operations, so I can select them from menu, in imenu-tree style.  I know about smex, that I can invoke with Meta-x.  But the visibility is hidden unless you enter Meta-x. These commands could be as simple as  'end-of-line', kill-word' etc ..

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small library, [`cmds-menu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/cmds-menu.el), which does this. It adds submenu `Recent Commands` to menu-bar `Tools` menu.

The library is loaded automatically, if available, when you load library [`menu-bar+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/menu-bar%2b.el).  See [MenuBarPlus](http://www.emacswiki.org/MenuBarPlus) for more about that library.